# How to remove refresh button on list view

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is there a chance to hide/remove refresh button on list view in aura component ? I have an aura component with list view from custom object. This component is visible on related lists, but the refresh button is not needed and I would like to remove it. 
For example inline edit I can hide using `enableInlineEdit="false"`. Maybe there is a similar way to hide refresh button ?

Does anybody know how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no option to remove this feature. If there were, it would be in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/specification).